# Alignment base on two reference nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I am new to `tikz`. If I have two nodes `[A]` and `[B]` as:

```
[A]

       [B]
```

How do I align `[C]` so that it is vertically below `[A]` and horizontally left of `[B]` such that:

```
[A]

[C]    [B]
```

without resorting to absolute positioning?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) at (0,0){[A]};
\node (b) at (5,-4){[B]};  
\node (c) at (a|-b){[C]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use relative positioning ([§ 3.8; TIKZ & PGF Manual, v. 2.10](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf)).

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{figure}
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
 \node [draw] (a) {A};
 \node [draw, below of=a] (c) {C};
 \node [draw, right of=c] (b) {B};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, if you need to place C after A and B. And in the question you need to place C after A and B. Another problem with this method appears with `scale=...`.

Comment: Not sure why you would *need* to place C after A and B, and not sure that the question implies that need. (The question does state the preference to avoid absolute positioning, and hence I still prefer my answer :P.)

Comment: The question begins with ` If I have two nodes [A] and [B]` Your method is correct in multiple cases like graphs in the tutorials of the pgfmanual, personally I tried to avoid it in the geometric pictures because it' s difficult to scale the result.

Comment: You could do `below right=of...` with the `positioning` library if you set `node distance=x<dimen> and y<dimen>` to the surrounding scope/tikzpicture.