# Node alignment on flowcharts

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

So, I'm building a flowchart based operation manual for the SEM at the lab that I work, and I'm having a trouble aligning a node with respect to two others.

I've seen already a few pages[[1]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38071/alignment-base-on-two-reference-nodes)[[2]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18389/tikz-node-at-same-x-coordinate-as-another-node-but-specified-y-coordinate)[[3]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63560/how-to-use-x-coordinate-of-a-point-and-y-coordinate-of-other-point?noredirect=1&lq=1)[[4]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263949/tikz-node-positioning-left-of-a-but-below-b?noredirect=1&lq=1) here that present the same problem and tried their solutions, but with no success what soever, so if someone can help me I would appreciate very much.

This is my MWE:

```
%%%  DOCUMENT SETTINGS  %%%
\documentclass[12pt, a3paper]{article} %page type
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} %margins
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{indentfirst} %indenting package
\setstretch{1.5} %between lines spacement
\setlength{\parindent}{1.5cm} %first line indentation

%page settings
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} % seting to use the customizable head and footers
\fancyhf{} % cleaning standard head and footers to use the new one
\rfoot{Autores: Eduardo de Almeida Isoppo;\\Luiz Felipe Pompermaier.} % page number on the footer's right side
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %remove the line on the headers
\usepackage{float} % tables and figures in multicols.

%font and language configs
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} %letter type
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %normal acentuation
%\usepackage{arial}
    % using pseudoarial font Helvetica.
    \usepackage{helvet}
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%Reference configs
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=red,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=magenta,
    urlcolor=blue,
    breaklinks=false,
    pdfauthor={Luiz Felipe Pompermaier}
    }

%image config
\usepackage{graphicx} % Image using package
%\graphicspath{{Imagens/}} % Image path
\usepackage{caption} % Image, tables, and others captions.
\usepackage{subcaption} % SubImage package. More then one per line.

%math config
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% text packages
\usepackage{blindtext} % lorem ipsum
%\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{titling} % used to make title higger in page
\usepackage{sectsty} % section title
\sectionfont{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont} %changing section fontsize
\usepackage{multicol} % multiple columns
\usepackage{xcolor} % coloring text
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % no hyphenation
\usepackage{microtype} % better justification
\usepackage{tcolorbox} % text in coloured boxes

% tikz package for flowchart drawings
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-layers}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

% Flowchart configs
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [ellipse, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm,text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, aspect=2, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth, line width=2pt]

\newlength{\AL}
\setlength{\AL}{2cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \Huge \textbf{Fluxograma de Operação do MEV}
\end{center}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % Nodes and texts
        \node (SftWrk) [decision, below=\AL of ScrnON] {Software está funcionando?};
        \node (SftErr) [process, left=\AL of SftWrk] {Chame um Técnico};
        \node (VentCb) [process, below=\AL of SftWrk] {Ventilar câmara segurando \textbf{VENT}.};
        \node (SmplHd) [process, left=\AL of VentCb, dashed] {Montar Porta-amostras desejado.};
        \begin{scope}[on behind layer]
            \node (Sample) [io][fit=(SmplHd)]{};
        \end{scope}
        
        % Arrows
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \draw[arrow] (SftWrk) -- node[anchor=south] {\textbf{NÃO}} (SftErr);
            \draw[arrow] (SftWrk) -- node[anchor=east] {\textbf{SIM}} (VentCb);
            \draw[arrow] (Sample) |- ($(EvacCb)!.5!(VentCb)$);
            \draw[arrow] (VentCb) -- +(0,-\AL);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This is the result it produces (focusing on the area of interest):
[image]

And what I want is to align the `(SmplHd)` box below of `(SftErr)` and left of `(VentCb)`, if this makes sense to everyone reading this.

And to be more explicit about it, no the `at (SftErr|-VentCb)` command does not work.

For the complete compilation please check https://www.overleaf.com/read/nfyvphkggdny

Comment: Please make your code a *minimal* working example https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that Helpers don't want an unnecessarily lengthy code I guess!

Comment: Try  `\node (SmplHd) [process, left=1.5\AL of VentCb, dashed] {Montar Porta-amostras desejado.};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**
Extend of image fragment with two more nodes an slightly modified nodes shapes styles.

Like this?

[image]

This image fragment is produced by the following MWE (Minimal Working Example)

```
\documentclass[12pt, margin=3mm]{standalone}    % page type
\usepackage{helvet}
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                calc, chains,
                fit,
                intersections,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes.geometric,
            babel
                }
% Flowchart config
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
         base/.style = {draw=black, semithick, font=\small,
                        minimum height=9mm, text width=33mm, align=flush center,
                        outer sep=0pt},
    startstop/.style = {base,
                        ellipse, fill=red!30},
           io/.style = {base,
                        trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
                        fill=blue!30},
      process/.style = {base, fill=orange!30},
     decision/.style = {base, inner sep=1pt,
                        diamond, aspect=2, fill=green!30},
          arr/.style = {-Stealth, thick},
every edge quotes/.append style = {auto, pos=0.4, font=\footnotesize\bfseries},
  suspend join/.code = {\def\tikz@after@path{}} % for use in not showed image part
        }
\makeatother
\newlength{\AL}
\setlength{\AL}{12mm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = \AL and \AL, 
  start chain = going below
                        ]
% first branch (unfinished)
    \begin{scope}[nodes = {on chain, join=by arr}]
\node (ScrnON)  [process]   {Ligar Monitores};
\node (SftWrk)  [decision]  {Software está funcionando?};
\node (VentCb)  [process]   {Ventilar câmara segurando \textbf{VENT}.};
\node (EvacCb)  [process]   {Evacuar câmara segurando \textbf{EVAC}.};
   \end{scope}
% left from first branch
\node (SftErr)  [process,
                 left=of SftWrk]    {Chame um Technico};
\node (SmplHd)  [process, dashed,
                 at={(SftErr |- VentCb)}]   {Montar Porta-amostras desejado.};
\scoped[on background layer]
    \node (Sample) [io, fit=(SmplHd)]   {};
% second branch (unfinished)
    \begin{scope}[nodes = {on chain, join=by arr}]
\node (HeatON) [process, suspend join,
                right=2*\AL of ScrnON] {Subir corrente \textbf{devagar} até ponto de saturação.};
\node (SmpLct) [process]    {Localizar Amostra a ser analisada.};
\end{scope}
% third branch

% Arrows
\path
    (SftWrk) edge ["\textbf{NÃO}" '] (SftErr)
    (SftWrk) edge ["\textbf{SIM}"]   (VentCb);
\draw[arr]
    (SftWrk) -- (SftErr);
\draw[arr]
    (Sample) |- ($(VentCb.south)!0.5!(EvacCb.north)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

- In MWE are omitted all what is not relevant at drawing of the image.
- Used is recent syntax for determining of nodes shapes styles (with `\tikzset` instead of obsolete `tikzstyle`)
- Position of the node with dashed border is on intersection of vertical lines through above node and horizontal line through right node, i.e. by `at={(SftErr |- VentCb)}`.
- positions of nodes in other branches is planed to be determined by `chains` (indicated are only with two top nodes in the second chain)
- MWE code is significantly simplified. By used of `join=by ...` macro are drawn all connection lines between nodes of in branch, so they need to be draw only for nodes out of branches and between branches.

Comment: Thanks.
That helped a lot. I'm going to make the suggest changes slowly as I have time to do, but I'm already so grateful for you to point those little things that may seem pedantic for everyone else, but I take as an opportunity to improve my codes and keep myself up to date on the subject.